# Extra socket for Math node

Tags: python

I have added a new input socket for the Math node but it doesn't take it into consideration (it calculates merely the two default input sockets). Is it possible at all to force the Math node to take into account a supplementary socket?
[image]

Comment: You can add the socket, which I think is a bug, but it doesn't connect internally.  It would take a significant rewrite of the math node to allow such a thing.

Comment: And how did you add that socket?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady node = bpy.data.scenes["HDRI solely"].node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeMath')
node.inputs.new("NodeSocketFloat","Value")

Comment:  It's hilarious to me that you brute-forced an extra input socket onto a node! Then again, it's also perfectly reasonable to want that. Maybe submit a feature request to the developers instead? Certain operations (like Add) could be more useful if extendable by the user.

Answer (score 7):

No. Even if it’s technically possible, you shouldn’t go around modifying nodes that don’t belong to you—they are written with a specific set of sockets and properties in mind, and they will not magically adapt to some other configuration.

If you want to add three values, you will have to use two Add nodes. If you really want a three-socket Add node, you can wrap two Add nodes in a node group.

Comment: Hmm, probably you are right